# PhpStorm 2016.1.2 gives error when using bootstrap 4 modals

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, phpstorm

Back in PhpStorm 8.0.1 (before updating recently) my bootstrap modals used to work perfectly with this code but now PhpStorm says that file not found? which is quite weird here is the code:

```
 <form name="register" method="post" action="index.php">
                <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm margin-bottom-input">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="registeremail" placeholder="Enter your email">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm margin-bottom-input">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="registerusername" placeholder="Enter username">
        </div>
                <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm margin-bottom-input">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-unlock fa-fw"></i></span>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="registerpassword" placeholder="Enter password">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm margin-bottom-input">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-unlock fa-fw"></i></span>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="verifypassword" placeholder="Verify password">
                </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
            </form> 
        </div>
```

My php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {                       // On DOM ready
    $('#registerModal').modal('show');   // Show the modal
});
 </script> 
<?php } ?>
```

PhpStorm however, says "404 file not found".

Am I doing something wrong? This code in PhpStorm 8.0.1 works perfectly fine.
screenshot of modal:
[image: modal]

Comment: Details please (screenshots etc). So far I do not see how "bootstrap 4 modals" have to do with "404 error". What URL is used?

Comment: what do you mean what url is used? i can give u a screenshot i just edited the post and  put a screenshot

Comment: Where is the modal dialog, all i see in your HTML is a modal footer, which includes the closing form tag, kind of strange.

Comment: @DavidDomain i didn't include that but it's in the code

Comment: i just dont get it why it works on phpstorm 8.0.1 and not in phpstorm 2016..

Comment: Not your form. What URL do you see in the browser when this "does not work"?

Comment: @LazyOne http://localhost:63342/myprojectname/index.php  and the page displays 404 not found

Comment: You are using PhpStorm's built-in simple web server .. which at the moment (2016.x) has issue with serving POST requests (POST is often empty .. or 404/502 errors are shown). Use proper web server (Apache/nginx/IIS/etc) instead. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317

Comment: @LazyOne are you sure about that bro? because i'm sure using localhost? dont i have to pay to use web server?

Comment: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+Built-in+Webserver+in+PhpStorm . Why do you think you have to pay? Get Apache or whatever (e.g ready made bundle like XAMPP/WAMP/etc) and install it locally.

Comment: @LazyOne weird i did exactly what the article said and still not working..

Comment: That article just described what the built-in web server is. You are using it already (your URL tells exactly that). What you need to do -- is to NOT use it.

Comment: @LazyOne lol i'm sorry for being annoying but how can i stop using it? is there any article for that too?

Comment: 1) You need to have your own web server (local or remote -- whatever); 2) you need to configure it .. so that you can serve your files/site there (so that you can browse them in a browser); 3) Once #1 and #2 done -- in PhpStorm -- create Deployment entry of required type (e.g. "in place" or "local folders" - it all depends on your needs and how you will configure your web server) -- there you will have to specify the URL for your site. This URL will be used instead of built-in server.

Comment: @LazyOne alright i'm gonna do that but what is the risk of using old phpstorm version? is it that **bad**?

Comment: It's up to you. It's all about new features/improvements in functionality + new PHP languages support etc. If you were happy with your old version .. and you did not missed any of the functionality that latest version provides .. then keep using old version if built-in web server is a must for you (and you have no time or desire to setup proper web server).

Comment: @LazyOne that's a great answer. thanks for helping :)